# HttpMethod does not exist in the current context after upgrade to MVC5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5.2

After upgrading my MVC4 application to MVC5 and following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) i get a compilation error:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@model MyApplication.Models.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Home", HttpMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "Result" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.Partial("Partial")
    <div id="Result">
        @Html.Partial("AddPartial", Model);
    </div>
}
```

error CS0103: The name 'HttpMethod' does not exist in the current context

I got a reference to System.Net.Http.dll (4.0.0.0) in my project.

EDIT: After updating I still have a warning in the "manage Nuget Packages" saying that Some packages could not be completely uninstalled and telling me to restart VS, but that didn't work and the warning staya there.

Comment: Do you have any warnings indicating the assembly could not be loaded?

Comment: No just this one that I don't has anything to do with it: Some NuGet packages were installed using a target framework different from the current target framework and may need to be reinstalled. Visit http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages for more information.  Packages affected: CacheManager.AppFabricCache, CacheManager.Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Ajax.BeginForm** we need to pass Method in the `AjaxOptions` with property `HttpMethod` which takes string `POST` or `GET`:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Home", new AjaxOptions() 
                                      { 
                                        UpdateTargetId = "Result",
                                        HttpMethod="POST" 
                                      }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
}
```

while in **Html.BeginForm** we have to pass in the third parameter which is Enum `FormMethod` and in post case we use `FormMethod.Post`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Home",FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
}
```